# Tableview not showing all of PFQuery results

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm seeing some unexpected behavior in my tableview and I'm hoping someone can help point it out. I have 63 records in a Parse database called ShowContacts. However, my tableview is displaying records 1-13 three consecutive times. NSLog shows that all 63 are in my "items" array but they are not all being displayed in my tableview. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,
Darin

.m file

```
@interface ShowContactsViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[PFQuery clearAllCachedResults];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ShowContacts"];
query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyIgnoreCache;
[query orderByAscending:@"Name"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (id obj in objects)
        {
            [items addObject:obj];
        }
        self.items = items;
        NSLog(@"%@", objects);
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[objects count]); // 63 records according to NSLog
        [self.myTableView reloadData];
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
}
}
#pragma mark Table

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath        *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (nil == cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];

}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath        *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (nil == cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I cannot believe that I was trying to set the text inside the If. Been looking at it for an hour and didn't see it. Long day...